# Затруднение с вариантом реализации ввода исходных данных

Tags: c, файлы, динамические-массивы, геометрия

Есть задание, которое необходимо реализовать на С: Заданы координаты N точек. Найти длину наибольшего отрезка, соединяющего эти точки.

В задании, не указана n-мерность, но пусть точка задается через X и Y, следовательно у меня возникает вопрос - делать ли два массива одномерных, в одном из которых Xn, а во втором, на той же позиции в массиве Yn, или динамический двумерный? Вводить данные надо с файла /или с консоли.  Задавать размерность надо вручную перед вводом. Какой подход, как вы считаете, более удобен при обработке?

Comment: Да как угодно. Лично я бы делал один массив структур типа `struct point { int x, y; };` (или какого они там у вас типа). Так координаты одной точки всегда держатся вместе...

Comment: Спасибо за совет с структурами. Ранее не встречался с ними, не знал общую специфику.

Comment: Так как количество точек плавающее, я бы сделал список. Но со списком нужны навыки работы. `struct point { int x, y; }; struct node{ struct point p; struct node * next; };`

Comment: `Задавать размерность надо вручную перед вводом.` : вы про количество точек, или размерность пространства?

Comment: про количество точек